# Set __Viewstate's base-64 encoded string of an ASP page from an android application

Tags: android, asp.net, http-post, viewstate

I'm hosting a website which contains a textbox and a button. I would like to set the hidden field `__VIEWSTATE` of the `ASP` web page with the base-64 encoded string which i'm sending from my android application.

For accessing and setting the `__VIEWSTATE` from my android app i'm using the `httppost`. But this doesn't seem to work.

Is this the way to do it ?? Is this possible to do it ??

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve? Are you sure there is no other way to achieve your end goal? It sounds very much like a hack. Viewstate is often encrypted to prevent tampering.

Comment: I have a transaction to occur between an android phone & asp page where i have to input some text in a textbox and click a button on a asp page just by sending in a string which contains the `viewstate`, `eventvalidation` and the text. I'm planning to use this in a private network.